# How do I capture Perl's STDOUT in a variable?

Tags: perl

I am calling a function that writes to STDOUT using print. How can I capture this in a variable?

Note that all this happens within the same process.

Answer (score 18):

The new, cool way to handle this is with [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Capture-Tiny). You can use it surgically to affect just the part of the program where you need it without disturbing anything else. But, I'd probably do what [cjm recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508679/2766176) since that doesn't require a module.

Comment: One problem with using Capture::Tiny for this is that it has no way to capture only STDOUT and leave STDERR alone.  It always captures both, either separately or merged.

Comment: Well, not until somebody submits a patch. [RT #60515](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=60515):)

Comment: Follow up... Capture::Tiny was updated at some point after the comments above. It can grab just STDOUT and leave STDERR alone with 'capture_stdout'. There are other variants as well depending on what you want to do. Very useful module.

Answer (score 14):

If the code in question is not using STDOUT explicitly (i.e., it just does `print "..."`), you can use [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to change the filehandle that `print` uses:

```
my $output;
open(my $outputFH, '>', \$output) or die; # This shouldn't fail
my $oldFH = select $outputFH;
call_code_that_prints();
select $oldFH;
close $outputFH;

print $output;    # Here's what we collected
```

Using `select` makes it easier to restore STDOUT afterward.  Closing and reopening STDOUT is harder to undo.  Note that `select` does not affect STDOUT itself, so it doesn't affect external processes, but you said you didn't have any.  It also doesn't affect code that does something like `print STDOUT "..."`.

If the `select` method isn't sufficient for your needs, I'd recommend you try [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture::Tiny).  It can capture output from external programs and code that writes to STDOUT explicitly.  But it can't (currently) capture only STDOUT; it always captures both STDOUT and STDERR (either separately or merged into one string).