# capture Perl module standard output from prove

Tags: perl

How can I capture the `print` function output from a module to `prove` test output? For example:

`A.pm`

```
package A;

sub f {
  print "inside module A";
}
```

`a.t`

```
use Test::More;

ok(f(), "test f() side effects");
```

The example maybe a bit inappropriate, but the idea is to redirect the print output from `module A` to `test a`, suppose I am using `prove` not `perl` to run the test, is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3508679/223226

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily redirect the output during the test.

```
my $scalar;
open my $test_fh, '>', \$scalar;
my $old_fh = select($test_fh);    # $old_fh is probably STDOUT
f();
select($old_fh);
close $test_fh;
ok( $scalar eq 'inside module A', 'test f() side effects' );
```

This code uses a couple less common functions and idioms:

```
open $handle, '>', \$var
```

> opens an output handle. Output to that handle gets stored in the scalar variable `$var`

```
$old_handle = select($new_handle)
```

> sets the "default" filehandle, the one used by the `print` and `printf` functions when a filehandle argument is not provided. Usually the default filehandle is `STDOUT`. The return value is the existing default filehandle.