# How do I redirect eval output to a file?

Tags: perl, eval

I am writing a Perl script where I read files containing section Perl code and non Perl data.

After processing the files I write them to a temporary files (generated scripts) which is then executed using an `eval` command. I don't want to run the generated script separately as I need to use the variables in the main script to be interpolated in the generated scripts.

I need to redirect the output of the eval command to a file. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Steps in the script:

1. READ_FILE
2. Process file
3. Write back with temp file name
4. Read temp file (`my $file_name = read_file('temp_file_name')`)
5. eval (`eval $file_name`)

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is the output going to STDOUT?

Comment: Yes. It is currently printed on STDOUT.

Comment: Then you can use Capture::Tiny, put it in a variable and then write to a file from there. There are a couple of good answers around. I'll find a duplicate target.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3511098/1331451 is basic, I don't think it works as a canonical. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781408/1331451 is way better, but not the accepted answer so I wouldn't want to close with that. I'll write a new one for the time being.

Comment: Why not just `open` a file on `STDOUT`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done without any additional modules

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '>', 'foo.txt' or die $!;
my $old_fh = select $fh;

eval q{ print "Hello World!\n"; };

select $old_fh;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `capture_stdout` from [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) to grab the output of your `eval`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Capture::Tiny 'capture_stdout';

my $stdout = capture_stdout {
    eval q{print "Hello World!\n";};
};

open my $fh, '>', 'foo.txt' or die $!;
print $fh $stdout;
```

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR Answer

**[`use Capture::Tiny;`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny)** with `capture_merged()` or `capture()`.  You may use `capture_stdout()` if you like it as a shortcut.

### Output?  Which output stream?  STDOUT or STDERR?

According to Perl, output can be in the form of:

- `STDOUT` — Typically caused by `print()`, etc., statements.
- `STDERR` — Typically caused by `warn()`, etc., statements.

You can use Capture::Tiny to get `STDOUT` and `STDERR` merged:

```
my ($merged,  @result) = capture_merged { eval $codetoeval };
```

Or, you can use Capture:Tiny to get them separated:

```
my ($stdout, $stderr, @result) = capture { eval $codetoeval };
```

You also have the option of `capture_stdout()` and `capture_stderr()` if you only want those forms of output.  If you only have `print()` statements, then `capture()` and `capture_stdout()` will give the same results.

### Complete Demo

```
use Capture::Tiny ':all';
my $codetoeval = 'print "Hello, World!";';
my ($merged,  @result) = capture_merged { eval $codetoeval };
die "Merge Fail" if !@result;
print("Output : " . $merged);
open my $fh, '>', 'foo.txt' or die $!;
print $fh $stdout;
```

[**Full Working Online Demo at IDEOne**](https://ideone.com/DiQjou)

Output: `Hello, World!`