# Capture script output and process it before actual write

Tags: perl

I have control over a perl script which is early required from another one which is a CGI script. I need to capture all output of the main script and be able to change it somehow.

This is the actual chaining:

```
[index.cgi] > (require) > [header.pl] > (eval 'cat ...') > [my_script.pl]
```

I know I can use the END block to make the post-processing part at the end of the whole program, but I would need a way to start capturing all the output.

**EDIT**: I have just found [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny), which allows us to:

```
use Capture::Tiny ':all';

($stdout, $stderr, @result) = capture {
  # your code here
};
```

But that would require me to put all the code between curly braces, which is not viable since I don't have access to the main, calling script (which requires my script). This helps to clarify that I want to start capturing the output as soon as I execute the sentence.

Comment: You can't do that. The output buffer isn't accessible to Perl code. It's a horrible idea anyway: why can't you just print the right thing in the first place? It may help if you printed your output to a scalar variable. Then you can do what you like to that variable before finally printing it to the output.

Answer (score 2):

Place the following in the file executed by your caller.

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/actual_script "$@" | perl -pe's/.../.../g'
```

Answer (score -1):

This solved my problem:

```
my $OUTPUT;
my $OUTPUT_FH;
my $OLD_FH;

open( $OUTPUT_FH, '>', \$OUTPUT ) or die;
$OLD_FH = select $OUTPUT_FH;

END {
  select $OLD_FH;
  close $OUTPUT_FH;

  # Change the output
  $OUTPUT =~ s/pattern/replacement/flag;

  print $OUTPUT;
}
```

Solution worked from: [How to Capture STDOUT in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508630/how-to-capture-stdout-in-a-variable)

Comment: That isn't modifying Perl's output buffer, so it doesn't answer your question. It's outputting to a scalar variable, and is what I meant by *"It may help if you printed your output to a scalar variable"*. Please make your question about *what you want to achieve* instead of picking a solution and asking how to implement it..

Comment: You were right. I shall rephrase the question (so that it doesn't add noise to the future reader). What I asked for is something I _remembered_ I did in Perl, but actually it was PHP. That reinforces the need to ask for something to achieve rather than how to achieve a specific solution.