# How can I store Curl output into a file using Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a directory there are lots of .wav files. I read the data of each file through curl command and store it into different files.

This is not complete script. some part of the script -

```
@command= '--request POST --data-binary "@Raajpal_long.wav" 
 "https://xxxx.xx.xxxx:xxxx/SpeakerId
 action=search&confidence_threshold=0.0&number_of_matches=20&format=8K_PCM16"';

 $stdout=system("curl @command");
```

when I run the perl script it gives the output on command line window :

```
{"status": 0, "processing_time": 96.0, "enrollment_audio_time": 131.10000610351562, "matches": [{"speaker": "sw", "identification_score": 252.54136657714844}]}
```

I want to store this output into a file.

I used -

```
open (FILE, ">1.txt") or die "Unable to open "1.txt";
$stdout=system("curl @command");
print FILE $stdout;
```

It's save only zero(0);

Can any one tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508630/how-do-i-capture-perls-stdout-in-a-variable

Comment: @ChatterOne, I tried but not working in my script

Comment: If you already tried to use `Capture::Tiny` can you post the code?

Comment: You can't use `system` to capture output, you can use `qx`. https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

Comment: @xxfelixxx,`$stdout=qx("curl @command");` instead of `$stdout=system("curl @command");` but not working

Comment: Why do you mean by "not working"? I tried using `qx`, and it works as desired. Tell us *exactly* what happens when you use `qx` instead of `system` please. And show us your *real* code please (the last 3 lines don't compile, you need to escape the `"` around `1.txt` in the `die`).

Comment: Please note that `qx` is *not* a function, it's quote operator, so `qx("command")` won't work, since there are too many quotes. Use `qx(command)` or `qx"command"`

Comment: thanks @el.pescado ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use system to capture output, you can use backticks `` in place of system.

Something like:

```
my @command= '--request POST --data-binary "@Raajpal_long.wav"
 "https://services.govivace.com:49162/SpeakerId
action=search&confidence_threshold=0.0&number_of_matches=20&format=8K_PCM16"';

my $result = `curl @command`;

if ( $? == -1 ){
    print "\n Curl Command failed: $!\n";
} elsif ($? == 0 ) {
    print "$result\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're already shelling out to curl to make the request; it would be cleaner to just use curl's [`-o`/`--output`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o) option to write to a file instead of stdout.

> ```
> -o, --output <file>
> ```
>
> Write output to  instead of stdout. If you are using {} or [] to
>   fetch multiple documents, you can use '#' followed by a number in the
>    specifier. That variable will be replaced with the current
>   string for the URL being fetched. Like in:
>
> `curl http://{one,two}.example.com -o "file_#1.txt"`
>
> or use several variables like:
>
> `curl http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com -o "#1_#2"`
>
> You may use this option as many times as the number of URLs you have.
>   For example, if you specify two URLs on the same command line, you can
>   use it like this:
>
> `curl -o aa example.com -o bb example.net`
>
> and the order of the -o options and the URLs doesn't matter, just that
>   the first -o is for the first URL and so on, so the above command line
>   can also be written as
>
> `curl example.com example.net -o aa -o bb`